# What determines a DLL's "create time" in the ListDLLs output?

Tags: windows, sysinternals

I've run ListDlls on an EXE that I'm unsure should be running no my computer.  The dates are all over the place for the DLLs in the output.  I'm curious as to how the "create time" field is set.

Comment: Explain your question with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the question, `listdlls -v SomeProcess.exe` shows version information for the modules of that process like the below example, notably including a "create time" row.

```
0x000000006f630000  0xc000    C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL
        Verified:       Microsoft Windows
        Publisher:      Microsoft Corporation
        Description:    Base cryptographic API DLL
        Product:        Microsoft« Windows« Operating System
        Version:        10.0.18362.1
        File version:   6.2.18362.1
        Create time:    Wed Jul 15 19:07:02 2105

0x000000006f4b0000  0x67000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
        Verified:       Microsoft Windows
        Publisher:      Microsoft Corporation
        Description:    Microsoft Windows Sockets 2.0 Service Provider
        Product:        Microsoft« Windows« Operating System
        Version:        10.0.18362.1
        File version:   6.2.18362.1
        Create time:    Mon Feb 14 21:29:32 1983
```

ListDLLs extracts the creation time from the `TimeDateStamp` field in the file's [PE header](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#file-headers). If you have Visual Studio, you can see the PE header information with the [`dumpbin`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=vs-2019) utility. On my machine, the output of `dumpbin /headers mswsock.dll` starts with this:

```
Dump of file C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll

PE signature found

File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
               9 number of sections
        18AF169C time date stamp
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
            2022 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
                   DLL
```

The "time date stamp" there is the hexadecimal representation of the Unix epoch-based time, the number of seconds since midnight (UTC) on January 1, 1970. Pasting `18AF169C` into [this online converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/hex) produces a local time of Monday, February 14, 1983 9:29:32 PM, which is what ListDLLs said.

As for *why* the timestamps are so wildly incorrect, I suspect that field is intentionally being filled with data that depends only on the source code, not the build time. ([Reproducible builds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducible_builds) make it easier to check that the binary hasn't been tampered with.) The "timestamp" is probably some kind of hash, which ideally are evenly distributed over the space of possibilities.